# Running hive script script through oozie but status is only RUNNING

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am trying to run hive script in oozie, but status is only RUNNING from long time, it is not changing only.

```
Workflow Name : hive-wf
App Path      : /user/root/oozie-scripts/hive
Status        : RUNNING
Run           : 0
User          : root
Group         : -
Created       : 2018-01-30 14:55 GMT
Started       : 2018-01-30 14:55 GMT
Last Modified : 2018-01-31 06:30 GMT
Ended         : -
CoordAction ID: -
```

what might be the problem?
and some time i am getting like `No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000020-180130125806084-oozie-oozi-W@hive-9ceb`

Comment: That log message is normal.You should get the external ID for the action and investigate the logs in that job. You can run oozie job -info <Workflow ID> to get the external ID.

Answer (score 0):

check the resource manager for the logs.The tasks might not be getting sufficient resources.Increase the mem/resources for the application master